# Continue script while a command is still executing

Tags: python

I want to play a sound effect, but continue the script while the sound is playing.
I am using "playsound" to play the audio
Currently it seems subprocess is what i need

There may be a better solution to solve this problem

```py
import subprocess
from playsound import playsound

subprocess.Popen(
    playsound("audio.mp3")
    )

#Code while audio is playing
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to run i in a separate thread. [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

Comment: Thanks Ray Toal for fixing the formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using threading. Sample below:

```
from playsound import playsound
import threading

def play_music():
    print 'Playing ....'
    playsound('<Music file path>')

#create thread to play music
t1 = threading.Thread(target=play_music)
t1.start()

#your code
for i in range(0, 10):
    print i

#wait for music to complete
t1.join()
print 'End'
```